# Update a value till it equals a certain value

Tags: arrays, if-statement, while-loop, iteration

```
a = 50.1233  # Need this value for every value in "b"

b = [50.1233,40.1241,52.1233,5.4124,12]

b_new=[]
for i in b:
    b_new.append(i)
    print(i)
    while i < b:
        i=i+1
        print(i)
```

I don't understand how to make every value in "b" 50.1233
I am confused.

Comment: Are you perhaps looking for `b[:] = [50.1233 for _ in b]`?

Comment: Can you instead help me with http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35857457/replacing-the-old-numbers-in-a-list-with-new-numbers-and-create-a-new-array