# Replacing the old numbers in a list with new numbers and create a new array

Tags: python, arrays, excel, if-statement, for-loop

```
import xlrd
fileWorkspace = '/Users/Bob/Desktop/'

wb1 = xlrd.open_workbook(fileWorkspace + 'Book1.xlsx')
sh1 = wb1.sheet_by_index(0)

colA,colB,colC,colD = [],[],[],[]
for a in range(3,sh1.nrows):
    colA.append(int(sh1.cell(a,0).value))
    colB.append(float(sh1.cell(a,1).value))
    colC.append(str(sh1.cell(a,2).value))
    colD.append(str(sh1.cell(a,3).value))
print(colA)
print(colB)   # Need to add 10 if indicated
print(colC)
print(colD)   # Adding 10 is indicated by "add10" 
print('\n')

update_colB_values = []
for i in range(3,sh1.nrows):    
    if sh1.cell(i,3).value == "add10":
        add = (sh1.cell(i,1).value) + 10
        update_colB_values.append(add)
print(update_colB_values)
```

I am getting all the new values for the values that has "add10" beside them. How do I create an array that replaces those values that had "add10" beside them with the new ones?

Initially pulled from the excel file ColB prints:

```
[32.0, 5.0, 12.0, 1.0, 87.0, 9.0]  # This is fine
```

After the update, I want to have a list that updates the list because 10.0 has been added to them. So, the new colB should be:

```
[42.0, 15.0, 12.0, 1.0, 87.0, 19.0]   # new_colB. This is what I want after the update.
```

The whole output as of now:

```
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
[32.0, 5.0, 12.0, 1.0, 87.0, 9.0]
['', '', '', '', '', '']
['add10', 'add10', '', '', '', 'add10']


[42.0, 15.0, 19.0]
```

Excel file image:
[Excel File](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6Vpda.png)

Answer (score 0):

Right now you are only appending the values to the updated list that have been changed. Instead, you want to append *all* values, while updating the values that need to be added to. Here's a form using your existing columns with a list comprehension:

```
colB = [32.0, 5.0, 12.0, 1.0, 87.0, 9.0]
colD = ['add10', 'add10', '', '', '', 'add10']

update_colB_values = [B + 10 if D == 'add10' else B for B, D in zip(colB, colD)]
# [42.0, 15.0, 12.0, 1.0, 87.0, 19.0]
```

You should be able to replace your instantiation and `for` loop with this line.

It should be noted that the built-in `zip` is a very useful function that you may be able to utilize in your earlier code. For example, it's base behavior is to "tranpose" a 2D list.

```
matrix = [['a1', 'a2', 'a3'],
          ['b1', 'b2', 'b3'],
          ['c1', 'c2', 'c3']]

for row in zip(*matrix):
    print(list(row))

# ['a1', 'b1', 'c1']
# ['a2', 'b2', 'c2']
# ['a3', 'b3', 'c3']
```

The function `zip` takes an arbitrary number of positional arguments and matches all the `ith` elements together. As soon as one of the rows is exhausted, iteration ends, so `zip_longest` (Python 3) or `izip_longest` (Python 2) from `itertools` is useful if you want to pad.

To do this using your existing code, you can add an `else` statement so that you include the elements that *don't* need 10 added to them.

```
update_colB_values = []
for i in range(3,sh1.nrows):    
    if sh1.cell(i,3).value == "add10":
        add = (sh1.cell(i,1).value) + 10
        update_colB_values.append(add)
    else:                                    # add
        value = sh1.cell(i,1).value          # these
        update_colB_values.append(value)     # lines
```

Comment: That one line of code did the job, but is there a way to do it without the zip because I have never used it, and I just want to stick with for-loop and if-statements.